# Upload file and object detail at the same time with Spring MVC 4 in a RESTFull server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, postman

I suppose to write a REST API which receives an Object detail (such as title, description, ..) and plus a File.

Spring request is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Content create(Content content,
        @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) CommonsMultipartFile fileData){...}
```

the Content is:

```
public class Content{
    String title;
    String description;
}
```

I send POST data with POSTMAN as described in this tutorial: [video on sending multipart/form-data requests](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vqvZmP28KE)

But both content and fileData are null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring use parameter revolvers to resolve controller parameters from HTTP request. Base on the java doc of org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver:

> There is no default resolver implementation used for Spring
>   DispatcherServlets, as an application might choose to parse its
>   multipart requests itself. To define an implementation, create a bean
>   with the id "multipartResolver" in a DispatcherServlet's application
>   context. Such a resolver gets applied to all requests handled by that

In the other hand there are several implementation for multi-part resolver:

- CommonsMultipartResolver
- StandardServletMultipartResolver

Where the first one use commons-fileupload. So at first I add following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

And finally, create a bean as follow:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000" />
</bean>
```

And all works

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar request and it worked based on the code below,

The number of variable in the service should match your call and ensure the name of the variable matches in your call. If Content is an object, ensure it matches the bean class Content.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Content create(@RequestParam("content") Content content, @RequestParam(name = "fileData", required = false) MultipartFile fileData){
   ...
}
```

I am not sure how you are sending or calling this service.

Answer (score 0):

This my sample code. point is form-data in RequestBody(postman).

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String testFormData(FileAndContentModel model) {
   // break point and check model.

   return "success";
}
```

**Model**

```
public class FileAndContentModel {

    private MultipartFile file;
    private String title;
    private String content;


    public FileAndContentModel () {
    }

     // getter, setter


}
```

**Postman**
[image]

Comment: The object is created but all params are null.

Comment: Your object model all null? if you don`t take error?

Comment: You need to put json library and MultipartResolver library in your project. ex) pom.xml and library folder